# how to add line break in Angular pipe output

Tags: angular, pipe

How can I  add a line break by using an Angular pipe

`<th>{{(date | date: 'EEE MMM d')}}</th>`

The output of this is like Mon Jul 20 - all in the same line.
But I want it separate like:

Mon
Jul
20

In same cell but on a different line. Like adding a `<br>` tag. Please check the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<th>
  {{(date | date: 'EEE')}}<br/>
  <strong>{{(date | date: 'MMM')}}</strong><br/>
  {{(date | date: 'd')}}
</th>
```

**Update** in case we have an array with property "date", we can add new properties to the array to improve the perfomance

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import { Component, LOCALE_ID, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string){}

//in somehwere
this.myArray.forEach((x:any)=>{
   x.dateEEE=formatDate(x.date,'EEE',locale)
   x.dateMMM=formatDate(x.date,'MMM',locale)
   x.dated=formatDate(x.date,'d',locale)
}
```

To import dinamicaly locate see [this link](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dynamic-import-of-locales-in-angular-b994d3c07197)

Comment: works but performance? what if you have 100s of columns

Comment: @dvdmn, in this case it's better calculate one time adding a new propertes to the array, see my answer updated

Answer (score 5):

My first solution was also to create a pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'breakOn'})
export class BreakOnPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]) {
    return value.replace(/,|;/g, '<br>'); //replace all ',' and ';' with <br>
  }

}
```

Similar to @Davis Jahn's answer. But this just shows the `<br>` in my table and no actual line break. The reason is that the string is "escaped".
**Solution:**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><span innerHtml="{{ row.value | breakOn }}"></span></td>
```

`<td>` does not seem to support "innerHtml" but `<span>` does.

Comment: I agree, but wouldn't `[innerHtml]="row.value | breakOn"` be better?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually try to implement a pipe which is defining a new line.

something like this:

```
@Pipe({ Name: 'addLine' })
Export class addLinePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: string[]): any {
      return value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');
  }
}
```

and then call it between your other pipes:

```
<th>
  {{date | date: 'EEE')}}
  {{foo | addLine}}
  {{date | date: 'MMM')}}
  {{foo | addLine}}
  {{date | date: 'd')}}
</th>
```

Comment: this just add "<br>/" as string

Comment: @dermoritz this is exactly what the OP wanted. The Question is "How can I add a line break by using an Angular pipe"

adding a <br>-tag (br = line break; source: MDN web docs) with an angular pipe is exactly that.

Comment: i added an answer. with your solution you will just see <br> in your table.